# Difficulties with understanding reallocating using malloc

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, runtime-error

I am trying to increase the size of my `collection` structure using `malloc` instead of `realloc`. I'm afraid I've made mistakes while assigning variables because I'm getting:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x7fd46b404ac8: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

I would really appreciate if you could give me a helpful hint.

```
void increaseCollectionSize(){
  collection.size = (collection.size + 1) * REALLOCATE_MODIFIER;
  char **increasedCollection = malloc(sizeof(char *) * collection.size);
  char **increasedHead = increasedCollection;
  for(int i = 0; i < collection.numberOfWords; i++){
    *increasedCollection = *collection.words;
    increasedCollection++;
    collection.words++;
  }
  free(collection.words); // I'm getting error here.
  collection.words = increasedHead;
}

typedef struct Collection{
  char **words;
  size_t numberOfWords;
  size_t size;
} Collection;
```

Comment: Where is collection.words assigned?

Comment: Look at the very first call when you're setting up `collection.words`. Are you malloc-ing that memory?

Comment: `*increasedCollection = collection.words[i];`..then remove `collection.words++;`

Comment: c programming without a useful debugger is like diving in shark waters with a dead and bleeding cow tied to your legs. <<-- don't do it.

Comment: @user2225104 In my decade+ practice, the most useful debugger is a fprintf(stderr) trace, especially in thread/async debugging. Anyway, one can't get it until he realizes that a pointer doesn't point to start of block anymore. How can "a useful" debugger help with that logical error?

Comment: @user3125367 In my 3 decade+ practice, the most useful debugger is a debugger along with writing (unit) testable code. If you make it a habit to single step your new code twice with a debugger, once with focus on control flow and once with focus on data values, you would find that logical bug in no time. That tip is also advertised in "Writing Solid Code", a book I strongly recommend. It is simply a waste of time to find logical errors in a full runtime environment.

Comment: @user2225104 Well, my funding and timelines are pretty concise to single-step twice into such triviality, but I still have 2 decades to get to that point :) Full RT – agreed, and thanks for the book!

Comment: @user3125367 All it takes is to sit a few times at the customers place and find a silly bug there while they look over your shoulders. Then, subsequently having to waste time with frustrating scolding and discussions. After a few times of that, one prefers to spend the time one has on proper testing than on frustrating social interactions ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You free the final value of `collection.words`, which is a pointer to the end of original memory block (due to ++ in a loop).

```
void increaseCollectionSize(){
    collection.size = (collection.size + 1) * REALLOCATE_MODIFIER;
    char **increasedCollection = malloc(sizeof(char *) * collection.size);
    char **increasedHead = increasedCollection;
    char **originalWords = collection.words; // save a pointer
    for(int i = 0; i < collection.numberOfWords; i++){
        *increasedCollection = *collection.words;
        increasedCollection++;
        collection.words++;
    }
    free(originalWords); // now ok
    collection.words = increasedHead;
}
```

Or, reducing the complexity:

```
void increaseCollectionSize() {
    collection.size = (collection.size + 1) * REALLOCATE_MODIFIER;
    char **increasedCollection = malloc(sizeof(char *) * collection.size);
    assert(increasedCollection != NULL); // explicitly abort() on malloc() error

    for (size_t i = 0; i < collection.numberOfWords; i++)
        increasedCollection[i] = collection.words[i];

    free(collection.words);
    collection.words = increasedCollection;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! May I have one question? What does it mean `FIXME assert`?

Comment: If you don't write sml "malloc check needed" comment after malloc(), you're guaranteed to get a bunch of comments that you should have mention it in the answer. That's the nature stackoverflow.com ;) Same with "DO NOT cast malloc" and "DO NOT (sizeof(char) * x)". Added an example. @MateuszPiotrowski